# Upgraded Snow Leopard to Lion MBA, no option for local snapshots in Time Machine

Tags: osx-lion, time-machine

I am trying to check my [local snapshots](http://support.Apple.com/kb/HT4878) on an upgraded Lion Macbook Air, but there doesn't seem to be any options for local snapshots in my Time Machine options preferences.

Am I missing something to enable this?

I am using Time Capsule for the backups - over WiFi.  The machine has only been backing up for just over a day.

This command line check gives an error:

```
tmutil snapshot
Failed to send message because a remote port for 'com.Apple.mtmd' couldn't be created. (error 255)
```

EDIT - just remembered that the TM backups were originally started under Snow Leopard - wonder if that could be the issue - do I need to start a fresh Lion based backup to get the option...Nope - not that, I have a Mac Mini that was on Lion before I got the Time Capsule, it also has no local snapshot options :(

Answer (score 0):

Tracked down this tip from the Apple forums showing how to turn local snapshots on/off

http://web.me.com/pondini/Time_Machine/30.html

Running the enable command seems to have enabled them - perhaps they are off by default following an upgrade or maybe my diskspace is on the low side...